# Cloud Functions document copy

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Cloud functions**

1. I want to read the document and edit some fields to add it as a new document.
   How can I do that?

const newData = value.data(); //<<< field modification

2. And can I use copyWith ?

Code:

```
exports.productCopy = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context)=>{

    const uid = context.auth.uid;

 



    data.selectedProductId.forEach((docId){
        const productRef = admin.firestore()
                 .collection('products')
             
                 .doc(docId);
        const newProductRef = admin.firestore()
                         .collection('products')
                  
                         .doc();

        const product = await productRef.get().then((value)=>{
            const newData = value.data();

            newProductRef.add(value.data())
        });



    });


    return {status:'success', isError: false};


});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, is good to know that each document is immutable, after you get a document in a variable you can modify that variable, and then you will need to put/update/patch the new document.

I meant you need to do 2 API calls, to save correctly the document in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It has saved me a lot of time.
I hope Firebase provides a more convenient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use `await` in `forEach` block. If you want to wait for multiple actions, use `Promise.all()`.

It should be something like this:

```
exports.productCopy = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const uid = context.auth.uid;

    const promises = data.selectedProductId.map((docId) => {
        return admin.firestore() //  Return promise, which bubbles up
          .collection('products')                  
          .doc() //  You need to specify a document ID here, uid maybe?
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            const newData = doc.data();
            return admin.firestore() //  Return promise, which bubbles up
                 .collection('products')             
                 .doc(docId)
                 .add(value.data());
          });
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then((results) => { //  Wait for all promises to resolve
      return { status:'success', isError: false };
    })
});
```

In general it's best to not mix `async`/`await` with `then()`, as it's easy to get into situations as you had. Here, just using promises keep the code as simple as possible

Comment: The lambda passed to oncall can be async in order to use await on the call to `Promise.all` and avoiding use of `then`.  Also, the lambda you pass to map can also be async in order to avoid the call to `then`.  async functions implicitly (always) return a promise based on the use of `await` and `return` inside it.

Comment: This is a very important tip. thank you for telling me. For non-cloud functions, you can place await inside a for statement. Is it possible?